# Exchange Routing Engine will not start

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I am trying to get the Exchange Routing Engine to start on a Windows 2003 Server SBS box, to no avail.

I have followed TechNet's guide and have used the Windows 2003 Server CDs to reinstall Exchange using the /disasterrecovery setting, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exchange routing engine depends on the iis admin service. is the iis admin service running? are there any error messages when you manually try to start the exchange routing engine service? are there any events in the event log related to the routing engine? have you recently made changes to or had problems with iis on the server? are you able to start the imap or pop3 services?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any particular error message? Anything in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already tried reinstalling to no avail and this is a critical outage, it's probably time to call Microsoft Support.